# How to throw out spaces and underscores only from the beginning of the string?

Tags: r, regex

I want to ignore the spaces and underscores in the beginning of a string in R.

I can write something like

```
txt <- gsub("^\\s+", "", txt)
txt <- gsub("^\\_+", "", txt)
```

But I think there could be an elegant solution

```
txt <- "  9PM   8-Oct-2014_0.335kwh  "
txt <- gsub("^[\\s+|\\_+]", "", txt)
txt
```

The output should be `"9PM   8-Oct-2014_0.335kwh  "`. But my code gives `"  9PM   8-Oct-2014_0.335kwh  "`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to keep whitespace/underscores at the end of the string?

Comment: I don't actually. But I first wanted to remove the unnecessary charterers  from the beginning of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bundle the `\s` and the underscore only in a character class and use [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to repeat that 1+ times.

```
^[\s_]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbwxNS/1)

For example:

```
txt <- gsub("^[\\s_]+", "", txt, perl=TRUE)
```

Or as [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) points out in the comment, if only the first occurrence is being replaced you could use sub instead:

```
txt <- sub("[\\s_]+", "", txt, perl=TRUE)
```

Or using a POSIX character class

```
txt <- sub("[[:space:]_]+", "", txt)
```

More info about `perl=TRUE` and [regular expressions used in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/regex)

[R demo](https://ideone.com/eOGns9)

Comment: Implicitly you don't need `gsub` here, just `sub` would be fine, because there is only one start of the string +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is true, thanks for the comment!

Comment: When I test this code with my txt variable, it doesn't work. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @user243557 Did you try it like this https://ideone.com/eOGns9 or like this https://ideone.com/kYeyRm? I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: The second link worked. Thank you! But it also removes some spaces in the middle of the string in my large file. For example, "5AM  15-Aug-2014___1.201  kwh " returns "5AM15-Aug-2014___1.201  kwh ". The space after 5AM is also removed.

Comment: @user243557 You could use `sub` to replace only the first occurrence instead of gsub. Or else use `txt <- gsub("^[\\s_]+", "", txt, perl=TRUE)` I have added the updates to my answer. See https://ideone.com/xqnREM

Comment: Thank you! The last question please. Why didn't the same code work without the last argument? (perl = TRUE

Comment: That is explained on this page [Regular Expressions As Used In R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/regex) I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringr` packages offers some task specific functions with helpful names. In your original question you say you would like to remove whitespace and underscores from the start of your string, but in a comment you imply that you also wish to remove the same characters from the end of the same string. To that end, I'll include a few different options.

Given string `s <- "  \t_blah_ "`, which contains whitespace (spaces and tabs) and underscores:

```r
library(stringr)

# Remove whitespace and underscores at the start.
str_remove(s, "[\\s_]+")
# [1] "blah_ "

# Remove whitespace and underscores at the start and end.
str_remove_all(s, "[\\s_]+")
# [1] "blah"
```

In case you're looking to remove whitespace *only* – there are, after all, no underscores at the start or end of your example string – there are a couple of `stringr` functions that will help you keep things simple:

```r
# `str_trim` trims whitespace (\s and \t) from either or both sides.
str_trim(s, side = "left")
# [1] "_blah_ "

str_trim(s, side = "right")
# [1] "  \t_blah_"

str_trim(s, side = "both") # This is the default.
# [1] "_blah_"

# `str_squish` reduces repeated whitespace anywhere in string. 
s <- "  \t_blah     blah_ "
str_squish(s)
# "_blah blah_"
```

The same pattern `[\\s_]+` will also work in base R's `sub` or `gsub`, with some minor modifications, if that's your jam (see Thefourthbird`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185343/10191355)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stringr` as:

```
txt <- " 9PM 8-Oct-2014_0.335kwh "
library(stringr)
str_trim(txt)
[1] "9PM 8-Oct-2014_0.335kwh"
```

Or the `trimws` in Base R

```
trimws(txt)
[1] "9PM 8-Oct-2014_0.335kwh"
```

Comment: OP only wants to remove "spaces and underscores in the beginning of a string".